# Search a .csv file for name match in C

Tags: c, search, csv, find, replace

I currently have a .csv file containing three fields: user, password, type. For instance, my file looks like this:

```
michael, sun123, user  
joseph, sierra7, user  
isaac, apple2, sysop
```

I would like to read from such file and check if the user "isaac" is present in the list. So far, I was able to open the file and put every characters of my file into a 1D array called database[]. I have set a pointer pointing to the very first character of my database[] array. My question is: How do I manage to find "isaac" in the file?

My idea was to check if the first character of the user I am looking for matches a character in my array. If so, I begin to check the next characters as long as I don't hit a comma. When I hit a comma, I then check if there exits a password, a comma and a type before a carriage return using boolean. Is there an easier way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `fgets`, `ststr`. Should take about a dozen lines of code. Or come to your senses and use `grep` (or `findstr` if you're on Windows).

Comment: You may be looking for http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the result of `strstr(database, "isaac");` to find "isaac" in your `database[]`.

You can use `strtok` (or it's safe variants, detailed here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) to break your `database[]` up into more manageable items (ie. tokenize on commas and newlines) for your parsing needs.

A combination of `strtok` and `strstr` or `strcmp` may be what you want.

Comment: Thank you some much for your quick response! I will make great use of strstr. My only concern would then be, what if one user has the same username as another user's password? In my example, a user may have as a username: sierra7. What would be a good way of fixing this?

Comment: @iHubble: You use grep or findstr and enter a pattern like `^sierra7` to signify that `sierra7` has to be at the beginning of the line. Alternatively, when you call `strstr` check whether it tells you the substring is at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Do you know where I could find more information about the strstr command? I would like to use it to check if the substring is at the beginning of a line. Perhaps I could check if *(&ptr - 1) == '\n' ?

Comment: @iHubble You can seek backwards for the '\n' character to ensure that you've found a username and count commas forward to identify user/sysop but it really seems to me that this process is made more complicated than it should be because `database[]` is a 1D array.  If you could process the file one line at a time, I think the code will be easier to write, cleaner, safer, and more reliable.  At that point, I'd consider using strtok to break each line into strings, trim whitespace with a loop, strcmp to identify the user and the user's privilege as user or sysop.

Comment: @antik Your idea seems good. I actually have to implement functions like add, delete, edit and verify. Working only on separate lines would actually be a lot easier when it comes time to edit things.