# Creating a LinkedList using sscanf in C

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, scanf

I need to implement a `LinkedList` from a file `.csv` file. My node is defined like this:

```
struct NODE {
    char username[50];
    char password[50];
    char usertype[50];
    struct NODE *next;
} *head=NULL;
```

I have put my whole `.csv` file inside an 1D array called `database`. I then want to `sscanf` this array and put each corresponding word inside a particular field inside my node. I have the following code written down:

```
void createList() {
    // I need a while-loop here //
    struct NODE* toAdd = (struct NODE*)malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));
    sscanf(database, "%[^','],%[^','],%[^'\n']", toAdd->username, toAdd->password,     toAdd->usertype);
    if (add(toAdd) == false) {
        printf("Error: was unable to initialize password validation!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

My `add` function looks like this:

```
BOOLEAN add(struct NODE *p) {
    if (p == NULL)   return false;
    if (head == NULL) {
        p->next = NULL;
        head = p;
    } else {
        p->next = head;
        head = p;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is there something wrong with the functions above? To sum up, I want to read from an array. I "break" this array into three-word-block, then assign the first one to the username field of the node, the second one to the password field, etc. I want to do this on my whole array, therefore creating one big `LinkedList` of nodes.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What did you learn from your previous questions?  In particular, [Reading .csv file into C linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465264/) and [Search a CSV file for name match in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434113/) are somewhat related to this — similar data structures.

Comment: I have just discovered `sscanf` and I would like to make use of it. I know that my questions are very similar.

Comment: It's not clear why you repeat the single quote in the negated scan-sets in the `sscanf()` format.  It isn't a major problem; just odd.  You don't limit the scan-sets to the space that's in the structure; you're vulnerable to buffer overflows.  You don't check that you got three fields from your input; always check the return value from `scanf()` and relatives.  You should check the memory allocation before you use the allocated space — at the moment, you wait until you get into `add()`, but that's too late; you've already crashed if something goes wrong.

Comment: And why are you asking whether there's something wrong?  Is the code working for you?  If not, you'd get more and better help with a description of what is going wrong and what you're doing when it does go wrong.  Ideally, you'd produce an SSCCE ([Simple, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) to demonstrate what's going wrong.  It's then easy to help you fix the issues.

Comment: It just does not compile. Is there any way to test if a node contains something in my list? That way I would know if it gets filled properly.

Comment: Then you need to (a) explain that in the question, and (b) show the compilation error messages you are getting, and (c) make sure we can see the minimal code that shows the errors.  How are we meant to guess what the trouble is?